# Looking for some tasks(school) for multidimensional arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array

Do you have any multidimensional arrays tasks. I need some to practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My teacher used in some cases multidimensional array in [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). To store the temporary result it needs an array. It is a characteristic of the problem: the grade? and that  requires the same level of multidimensional array. For eg if grade is 3 than you need to bypass an int[][][] to a resoveProblem() function.

If I would be teacher ever... I would search for a dynamic programming needed task and I would present the solution with multi array. Hopefully the students will realize the execution speed difference and will solve, exercise the matrices problems too.

Task2: you can invent a text why is needed to be stored the data in 1 dimension of array, for eg need to save data to file, than a bit imagination why need 2 dimensional array to use the loaded data in a virtual chessboard. Than they must do the 1 dimension to 2 dimension conversion

Answer (score 0):

multiply matrices

Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 17

Comment: I got that one, add or multiply but can't figure out anything better.

Comment: I am sorry it is not helpfully, but only this requires truly multidimensional. It is not mentioned to not be matrix opetations